# Create own social login page with lightning component

Tags: community, single-sign-on, login, auth

I did Auth Provider and built the community with experience builder. Login page has username, password and social sign on button with experience builder page but I need to change the layout out and size.I can't change the size the login page and layout at experience builder. I have no idea how to continue.

I want to know how to create own Salesfore community Single Sign On login page witn lightning component. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. We generally cannot provide complete designs or step-by-step instruction, but we're happy to help you with issues you encounter in your own implementation process. For more about our format, please take the [Tour] and read [ask]. Please [edit] your question to show us *what you've tried* and *where you are stuck*.

Comment: I did Auth Provider and built the community with experience builder. Login page has username, password and social sign on button with experience builder page but I need to change the layout out and size.I can't change the size the login page and layout at experience builder. I have no idea how to continue.

Comment: Please **[edit] your question** to specifically describe your problem.

Comment: I saw loginform and other aura component in aura folder, but doesn't have social login aura component in aura folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the correct path and have followed the steps correctly. Doing those things will indeed allow you to social sign in to the standard page.

There are two ways to change the look and feel.

**Limited way:**

Change the global CSS in community builder. You will have control over look and feel of the buttons

**Explicit way:**

You need to either create an Aura (recommended)/LWC or a VF page which contains one button, on click of that button you can add the single sign-on URL generated in Auth provider. [This](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_login_self_reg_lightning.htm&type=5) and [this](https://sfdcbrothers.wordpress.com/2017/11/01/custom-community-login-lightning-component-salesforce/) should be a good starting point should you need to modify standard login via username and password.

Comment: @manjiti5190 Thank you so much. > you can add the single sign-on URL generated in Auth provider. single sign-on URL means authorize endpoint?

Comment: It would be the SSO initialization URL at the bottom of Auth Provider in `communities` section

Comment: Thank you so much. OK, I See. I'll try later. Can I retrieve SSO initialization URL and other Auth Provider's info from apex?

Comment: You can use the relative URL or store it somewhere in metadata or a label because your guest user will need access to it.

Comment: I created custom Aura login page but it wasn't shown in Community > Administration > login& registration > login page type > experience builder page. How can I set my custom login page to as community's default login page.